# MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, zabbix, agent

I create yaml file for creating container on docker:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: 'MySQL'
    image: 'mysql'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'zabbix_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'zabbix_user'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'zabbix_password'                                                                                     volumes:                                                                                                                   - './mysql:/var/lib/mysql'                                                                                           ports:                                                                                                                    - '3306:3306'                                                                                                         restart: 'on-failure'                                                                                                 zabbix-server:                                                                                                            container_name: 'Zabbix-server'                                                                                         image: 'zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql'
    environment:
      ZBX_DBTLSCONNECT: 'required'                                                                                      #      DB_SERVER_HOST: '127.0.0.1'                                                                                      #      DB_SERVER_PORT: '3306'                                                                                                 MYSQL_USER: 'zabbix_user'                                                                                               MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'zabbix_password'                                                                                       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'zabbix_db'                                                                                           ports:                                                                                                                    - '10051:10051'                                                                                                       depends_on:
      - 'mysql'    
 zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:
    container_name: 'zabbix-web-nginx-mysql'
    image: 'zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql'
    environment:
      BX_DB_ENCRYPTION: 'true'
#      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
#      ZBX_SERVER_PORT: '10051'
#      DB_SERVER_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
 #     DB_SERVER_PORT: '3306'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'zabbix_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'zabbix_user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'zabbix_password'
      PHP_TZ: 'Asia/Tehran'
    depends_on:
      - 'mysql'
      - 'zabbix-server'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  zabbix-agent:
    container_name: 'Zabbix-agent'
    image: 'zabbix/zabbix-agent'
    environment:
      ZBX_HOSTNAME: 'srv197189'
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
      ZBX_ACTIVESERVERS: '127.0.0.1:10051'
```

in this yaml file use `mysql, zabbix-server`, `zabbix-web-nginx-mysql` and `zabbix agent`.
when i run `sudo docker-compose up`, `mysql` create sucesssfully but `zabbbix-server` and `zabbix-web-nginx-mysql` get the following error:

```
 MySQL server is not available. Waiting 5 seconds...
```

in other way i install `mysql` in system (not docker) but get mentioned error.

Comment: Does the second attempt to connect, after 5 seconds, work?

Comment: No do not connect when i run `sudo docker-compose up`. @HansKilian

Answer (score 1):

Your zabbix-web-nginx-mysql container is unable to connect to your mysql server with your current settings/configuration.
docker-compose creates a default network where all your containers are joining so they are able to communicate with each other.
All your containers can reach each other by using their service name defined in your yml file.
So you just have to uncomment

```
DB_SERVER_HOST: '127.0.0.1'
```

and replace it with

```
DB_SERVER_HOST: 'mysql'
```

Now your container should be able to reach and connect to your mysql database.
Also keep in mind 127.0.0.1 is not your host within a container!

Answer (score 0):

You can add following env variables:

`MYSQL_ROOT_USER=[your database user]`

`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[your database user password]`

This is needed to run some commands to initialize database;

You can try this variable to inspect:

`DEBUG_MODE=true`